# Wird »das Kommentar« salonfähig?

Tags: gender, article

In letzter Zeit sehe ich öfter mal, dass jemand

> das Kommentar

statt

> der Kommentar

schreibt, auch in Onlineprintmedien und in auf den ersten Blick sorgfältig geschriebenen Texten (z. B. [hier](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CF8QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Foehboku.at%2Fuploads%2Fmedia%2FDarstellungsform_Kommentar.pdf&ei=5IqIVJ6yKozuaI-IgvAP&usg=AFQjCNEGTVjUJdlypZoDepxtC6l5ExaArA&sig2=DMb00-ovGiTt3vM2sdK1sg&bvm=bv.81456516,d.d2s), [hier](http://kritischeunihro.blogsport.de/2014/02/04/offener-brief-an-ulrich-vetter-presseprecher-der-uni-rostock/), und [hier](http://politkom.wordpress.com/programm/abstract-pfurtscheller/)). Der Duden behauptet, *Kommentar* sei maskulin, ohne Ausnahme (im Gegensatz zu *Virus).* Stolpere ich über seltene Ausnahmen, oder wird die neutrale Form in der deutschen Sprache geläufig? Natürlich finden sich per Google etliche Diskussionen, aber mich würde die Meinung der Experten hier interessieren. 
Eventuell hat sogar jemand eine Erklärung für den Ursprung der neutralen Form?

Comment: Hoffentlich nicht. Für mein Gefühl klingt es als komme es aus dem Süden.

Comment: Ich hoffe doch auch nicht - aber der Süden (zumindest der Südwesten) ist unschuldig! Zugegeben, wir Schwaben "neutralisieren" schon mal, aber nicht "das Kommentar".

Comment: Auch in Österreich ist noch immer »der Kommentar« korrekt.

Comment: Das Dromedar, war immerdar, ein Exemplar, im Kommentar.

Comment: Der verlinkte Text hält selbst das falsche Geschlecht nicht durch: `Der Kommentar sollte sich nicht im „Ton vergreifen“ / Der Kommentar muss für die LeserInnenschaft geschrieben sein Æ viele VerfasserInnen schreiben sich in Wut und somit am Ziel vorbei / Der
Kommentar benötigt ...` - Das kaufm. Und ist hier auch falsch wie das große Binnen-I, insbes. in LeserInnenschaft . Womögliche ideologische Sprachsabotage mit Hintersinn auch beim Kommentar, der kastriert werden soll. Man kann nicht jeden gedruckten Fehler zum Ausgangspunkt einer Diskussion machen. Schließen!

Comment: @userunknown Der Fehler ist relativ häufig, wie die Antwort unten und die Diskussion im Internet deutlich machen.

Comment: @painfulenglish: Ich sehe unten nur eine Antwort z.Zt. und kann dieser keine relative Häufigkeit entnehmen. Was verstehst Du darunter, 5%?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Die falsche Verwendung von *Kommentar* mit *das* statt *der* in Texten deutschsprachiger Internetseiten ist auch der Redaktion des [*Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/) aufgefallen. Ein regionales Muster dieser Verwendung konnte jedoch nicht festgestellt werden.

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]